# Service running on nohup consuming lots of memory

Tags: linux, unix, nohup

I am running my rest-ful api with nohup ,what i have observed that with every request and response memory utilization increases. I am also storing the results in nohup.out.

Could anyone please help.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is rather unlikely that `nohup` causes your process to use more memory or leak it.

Run it without `nohup` and see if it still consumes an unexpected amount of memory. E.g. start it in `bash` using `(my-java-app &> output.txt </dev/null &)` (same effect as with `nohup`).

Comment: Yes,It looks like a code issue,thanks for your answer!!